# How to arrange CSS order on Production Build Vue?

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I have CSS issue in my project, I want my CSS to load like this
https://i.stack.imgur.com/8wB6R.png (1px border override 2px border) in my development environmet, but when I try it in my production environment it becomes like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/LdCOX.png (2px border override 1px border). This is my vuetify.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuetify from 'vuetify/lib'
import '../theme/default.styl'
Vue.use(Vuetify, {
  theme: {
    primary: '#ee44aa',
    secondary: '#59595c',
    accent: '#82B1FF',
    error: '#FF5252',
    info: '#2196F3',
    success: '#4CAF50',
    warning: '#FFC107'
  },
  customProperties: true,
  iconfont: 'fa4',
})
```

this is my main.js:

```
import Vue from "vue";
import './plugins/vuetify'
import App from "./App.vue";
import router from "./router/";
import store from "./store";
import "./registerServiceWorker";
import 'roboto-fontface/css/roboto/roboto-fontface.css';
import 'font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css';
import axios from "axios";
```

And this is my default.styl (Where I override Vuetify CSS):

```
@import '~vuetify/src/stylus/main.styl'
body
  font-family: "Poppins" !important
  font-size: $font-size-root
  font-weight: $font-weights.regular
  line-height: $line-height-root
h1
  font-size: 48px
  font-weight: $font-weights.thin
  letter-spacing: -1.5
```

Comment: Do not add code as pictures. Include the code into your question

Comment: Done and I add an extra code